# How to update delta table based on lookup DataFrame?

Tags: pyspark, delta-lake

I need to update delta table based on lookup file rows .

lookup file has two columns a_acc & b_acc, it will have mulitple rows.
i need to update b_acc value in delta table based on a_acc column value in lookup in delta table .

```
Lookup table
+------------
|a_acc|b_acc|
+-----------
| 4636|1999|
| 1023|892 |
| 3333|1111|


Delta Table
+------------
|a_acc|b_acc|
+-----------
| 4636|0123|
| 1023|843 |
| 3333|3232|

output Delta table:

+------------
|a_acc|b_acc|
+-----------
| 4636|1999|
| 1023|892 |
| 3333|1111|
```

For single single row i can update the values in delta table .

```
deltaTable.update(condition = "a_acc = '4636'",set = {"b_acc": "1999"})
```

But how can i loop all the value in lookup table and update correspondingly ?

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly [MERGE](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-update.html#upsert-into-a-table-using-merge) operation:

> You can upsert data from a source table, view, or DataFrame into a target Delta table by using the MERGE SQL operation. Delta Lake supports inserts, updates and deletes in MERGE, and it supports extended syntax beyond the SQL standards to facilitate advanced use cases.

You can use merge to update the values (b_acc) in delta table when matching key found in lookup table (a_acc).

```
deltaTable.alias("dt").merge(
    source = Lookuptable.alias("lt"),
    condition = "dt.a_acc = lt.a_acc"
  ).whenMatchedUpdate(set =
    {
      "b_acc": "lt.b_acc"
    }
  ).execute()
```

Comment: condition = "dt.a_acc = lt.a_acc" . .  this is only for matched condition .. it should take column b from lookup and update the value in delta ..

Comment: That is what I am trying to do with whenMatchedUpdate operation i.e updating values in delta tables b_acc using values from lookuptable's b_acc

Comment: Thanks @Anjaneya Tripathi  it works .. Additional information .. Can we add case statement inside update ? like case when a!=b & a==c then a=d .. something like that ?

Comment: You can have multiple whenMatchedUpdate each having own set of extra conditions like shown on [this](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-update.html#language-python) page

Comment: not sure if multiple updates works , its throwing error : INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE cannot appear twice in one MERGE query ..

Comment: I have multiple conditions. example  . 1) if (a=b & b!=c) then update z='Y' else if (a!=b & b=c) then update z='N' else if (a=b & b=c) then update z='T' else z='N' .. Can we do this through delta lake update ?

Comment: We can do and I think you are writing multiple updates in a single whenmatchedupdate so you can put it as a separate question and I can try to answer it

Answer (score 0):

hope this can help u.

```
d1 =[[4636, 1999],[1023,892],[3333,1111], [444, 123]]
lookup_table = spark.createDataFrame(d1, ['a_acc', 'b_acc'])
d2 =[[4636, 123],[1023, 843],[3333,3232], [567, 221]]
delta_table = spark.createDataFrame(d2, ['a_acc', 'b_acc'])

(
    delta_table
        .join(lookup_table.withColumnRenamed("b_acc", "lookup_b_acc"), ["a_acc"], "left")
        .withColumn("b_acc", coalesce(col("lookup_b_acc"), col("b_acc")))
    .sort("a_acc")
    .show()
)
+-----+-----+------------+
|a_acc|b_acc|lookup_b_acc|
+-----+-----+------------+
|  567|  221|        null|
| 1023|  892|         892|
| 3333| 1111|        1111|
| 4636| 1999|        1999|
+-----+-----+------------+
```